# Facebook Invite Gate - What code do I need to add?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am still a noob in programming so forgive me if the solution should be obvious.

I meanwhile managed to find this function on the FB developer's site:

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      redirect_uri: 'http://www.google.com',

    }, requestCallback);
  }
```

and made the actual window popping up with calling the function.

Now what I am missing is how can I make sure that the user actually did invite somebody and if he did forward him to page a and if not forward him to page b?

Thanks in advance.

-Gerd

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for what that function returns? You should be able to figure it out from that

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well as Igy pointed me in the right direction I found basically what I was looking for here:

["Request Dialog" requestCallback when clicking Cancel or Close button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765946/request-dialog-requestcallback-when-clicking-cancel-or-close-button)

Thus for everybody needing a like gate this would be the code to go with:

```
function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {

    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',

    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
   if(response && response.request) {
     // Here, requests have been sent, facebook gives you the request and the array of     recipients
     //console.log(response);
     location.href='success.php';
} else {
     location.href='cancel.php';
}
```

Hope that helps!

Cheers,

Gerd